# Problem when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, aws

I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server Express and I get this error. This happens both locally and on client.

> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the
>   post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting
>   for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have
>   timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections. The
>   duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was
>   [Pre-Login] initialization=216; handshake=7899;
>   [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0;
>   [Post-Login] complete=5999;  (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Can someone help me?

Comment: The version I use is 2014. I'm trying both using Windows auth or SQL auth

Comment: I am not setting, I'm only with 1 GB.

Comment: How do you have a version of Windows running on only 1 GB of RAM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>This answer is intentionally Community Wiki to encourage others to edit in other useful links and information for troubleshooting connection problems.</sub>

Please try:

- [Troubleshooting: Timeout Expired](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [How to Troubleshoot Connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx)

Both are Microsoft TechNet guides targeted at your type of problem.

- [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) wrote a blog post [listing many different error codes for login related connection errors](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456)

The Stack Overflow Q & A [Help troubleshooting SqlException: Timeout expired on connection, in a non-load situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421978/help-troubleshooting-sqlexception-timeout-expired-on-connection-in-a-non-load) provides lot of good pointers to check on a box facing this type of issue.